# objc custom classes and class methods

Tags: objective-c, class, methods

I need some advice with creating custom classes and methods.
I would like to create a custom class for doing calculations. The class should provide a method that could be called within a ViewController class. Within the ViewController a parameter (e.g. an array) is passed to the custom class method and a calculated value is returned setting an ViewController variable like that:

```
//called in ViewController.m
viewControllerObject   = [CustomClass customClassMethod:passedArray];
```

What do I need to know to realize that? And is that an acceptable approach?

EDTI:
my first try (don't laugh):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ShapiroWilk : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *pValue;

+ (id) SW_pValue:(NSNumber *)apValue;

@end
```

-h-file:

```
#import "ShapiroWilk.h"

@implementation ShapiroWilk

@synthesize pValue;

+ (id) SW_pValue:(NSNumber *)apValue
{
    ShapiroWilk *pValue = [[self alloc] init];

    pValue.pValue = apValue;

    //how would I calculate and return values to the calling controller?

    return pValue;
}

@end
```

Comment: I actually tried to create a class method like: `+ (id) customClassMethod:(NSArray *)aArray;` but I just don't understand how to set it up right. I always get errors like "two many parameters...".  A simple tutorial would help. What I've found so far is kind of confusing.

Comment: @JFS what you are doing is correct in principle. Show more code so we can help you

Comment: [Check out these tutorials.](http://www.icodeblog.com/tag/xcode/)

Comment: @bengoesboom, thanks for answering one of my questions.

Comment: @bengoesboom, would I better use an instance method here?

Comment: @JFS what you are doing is basically correct, but as far as I can tell there's no reason for you to be creating an instance of `ShapiroWilk` in your SW_pValue function. You should probably do some reading as to what the difference between class methods and instance methods are as you don't appear to know which to use when

Comment: @bengoesboom, I did some research and I think I start to understand better now. Thanks for your help!